# The functional is not continuous in respect to the strong norm

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity

Let $V=C^1([a,b])$. If $J$ is a continuous functional for the norm $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ then it is continuous for the norm $\|\cdot\|_1:= ||y||_{\infty}+||y'||_{\infty}, y \in V$. But the converse is false.

In my book there is the hint that we can use the functional of arc length, in order to show that the converse does not hold.

The functional is this: $J(y)= \int_a^b \sqrt{1+y'(x)^2} dx$, right?

I have tried the following:

If $y_1, y_2 \in V$ then:

$$|J(y_2)-J(y_1)|= \left| \int_a^b \sqrt{1+y_2'(x)^2} dx- \int_a^b \sqrt{1+y_1'(x)^2}dx  \right| = \left| \int_a^b (\sqrt{1+y_2'(x)^2}-  \sqrt{1+y_1'(x)^2}) dx  \right|= \left| \int_a^b \frac{y_2'(x)^2-y_1'(x)^2}{\sqrt{1+y_2'(x)^2}+ \sqrt{1+y_1'(x)^2}} \right| \leq\int_a^b \frac{|y_2'(x)^2-y_1'(x)^2|}{|\sqrt{1+y_2'(x)^2}+ \sqrt{1+y_1'(x)^2}|} dx \leq \frac{1}{2} ||y_2'-y_1'||_{\infty} (b-a)$$

But $||y_1-y_2||_{\infty}+||y_1'-y_2'||_{\infty}$ didn't appear. So have I done something wrong?

**EDIT**: So we can bound  $\frac{1}{2} ||y_2'-y_1'||_{\infty} (b-a)$ by $\frac{1}{2} (||y_2-y_1||_{\infty}+||y_2'-y_1'||_{\infty}) (b-a)$ and so we deduce that $J$ is continuous for the $||\cdot||_1$ norm, right?

But how could we show that $|J(y_2)-J(y_1)|$ is not bounded by $||y_1-y_2||_{\infty}$?

**EDIT**: Or do we have to consider an other counter-example?

Comment: You can trivially bound $\|y_1'-y_2'\|$ by $\|y_1-y_2\|+\|y_1'-y_2'\|$.

Comment: @daw A ok. And how could we show that $|J(y_2)-J(y_1)|$ is not bounded by $||y_1-y_2||_{\infty}$ ?

Comment: Try to find a sequence of functions which converges uniformly but the derivatives do not converge uniformly. For such a sequence the arc lengths probably don't converge. One possibility for such a sequence is $\sin(n^2 x)/n$ (although I haven't done the calculation with this example, so I can't promise that it is an easy calculation). The idea is that if the oscillation is centered at zero, then the sup norm is the amplitude, but the sup norm of the derivative is basically the amplitude times the frequency.

Comment: @Ian So you mean that we could consider for example the functional $J(y)=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \frac{\sin(n^2 x)}{n}$ ?

Comment: @evinda It's not really correct to call that a functional, each of those is a number. The point is that the sequence $f_n(x)=\frac{\sin(n^2 x)}{n}$ converges uniformly to zero, but its sequence of derivatives is $n \cos(n^2 x)$, which doesn't converge pointwise at all. Hence you might expect that the sequence of arclengths, i.e. the sequence of numbers $\int_{-\pi}^\pi \sqrt{1+n^2 \cos(n^2 x)^2} dx$, does not converge.